# Dynamically create textbox on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I have created a button whereby when it is clicked, it should display 3 textboxes in a row. However, every time i click the submit button, the textbox would display 2 rows(which is 6 textboxes). And subsequently increase 2 rows at every click.

Is there anyway that it could just increase one row of textbox at every click??

Here is the code infront:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>

</div>
</form>
```

Code Behind:

```
         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        // Add any controls that have been previously added dynamically
         for (int i = 0; i < TotalNumberAdded;  i++)
        {
        AddControls(i + 1);
        }

    // Attach the event handler to the button
    Button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // Increase the number added and add the new label and textbox
    TotalNumberAdded++;
    AddControls(TotalNumberAdded);

}

private void AddControls(int controlNumber)
{

        TextBox TxtBoxU = new TextBox();

        TextBox TxtBoxE = new TextBox();

        TextBox TxtBoxY = new TextBox();

        Label lblU = new Label();
        Label lblE = new Label();
        Label lblY = new Label();

        TxtBoxU.ID = "TextBoxU" + controlNumber;
        TxtBoxE.ID = "TextBoxE" + controlNumber;
        TxtBoxY.ID = "TextBoxY" + controlNumber;

        lblU.ID = "LabelU" + controlNumber;
        lblE.ID = "LabelE" + controlNumber;
        lblY.ID = "LabelY" + +controlNumber;

        lblU.Text = "User : ";
        lblE.Text = "E-Mail : ";
        lblY.Text = "Phone number : ";

        //Add the labels and textboxes to the Panel.
        Panel1.Controls.Add(lblU);
        Panel1.Controls.Add(TxtBoxU);
        Panel1.Controls.Add(TxtBoxU);

        Panel1.Controls.Add(lblE);
        Panel1.Controls.Add(TxtBoxE);

        Panel1.Controls.Add(lblY);
        Panel1.Controls.Add(TxtBoxY);
        Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));

   }

protected int TotalNumberAdded
{
    get { return (int)(ViewState["TotalNumberAdded"] ?? 0); }
    set { ViewState["TotalNumberAdded"] = value; }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tested your Code and when I clicked the button only I get one row.

Comment: really!? but i keep getting two rows instead of one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in your page load, becouse your `click event` declaretion is redundant, you are attaching the `EventHandler` when you are assinging by HTML, And If you push click the event, It is fires 2 time.

Remove

```
Button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);
```

And you page load will looks like:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    // Add any controls that have been previously added dynamically
     for (int i = 0; i < TotalNumberAdded;  i++)
    {
      AddControls(i + 1);
    }

  }
```

I hope that help.

P.S: I'm sorry in my first test I did not test right.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtobj = new TextBox();
    Form.Controls.Add(txtobj);
    txtobj.Text = "Dynamically Textbox";

}
```