# How to get newly created inputs from code-behind?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms, code-behind

I am trying to make a web survey application with Web Forms. 
The issue is I am having troubles with the survey creation part.

In the CreateSurvey.aspx I have a button which supposed to add options when clicked. Button will add new input areas for user to create new options. That part is easy. I can do that with code behind.

But the real issue is I need to get those values in order to show them while the survey has been answered. I need to write those inputs to my db. But I can't get those values because they haven't been created yet! What topic should I look into? Does anyone has a similar problem?

By the way if possible I am just looking for code behind solutions. Because of UpdatePanel of ASP.NET currently I am having some issues with the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there welcome to Stack! It is a little difficult to determine based on your question what the best solution for you would be, it would really help if you provided some code to look at. However, it sounds like you are trying to have a user create a survey with different fields, and then be able to have other users partake in that survey? If so, I would recommend you start with a strong db **schema** that can hold your survey questions **and** answers.

After creating the proper tables you will be able to save created surveys with all their associated questions to your db and then pull those surveys and present them to users. After the users have filled out the survey you will be able to save their answers in the appropriate table. How you create this schema is entirely up to you and there's a multitude of ways you can go about it. You can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764435/database-design-for-a-survey) post to get some good ideas. Hope that helps you out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that is not what I asked. My problem is to tell server there is a new input created by user and I want it to be stored. I’ve created all my databases. I have an add option button. When User clicks this button I want a new field pop up and have it stored.

Comment: All the solutions I’ve found contains JS and this is something I’m trying to avoid. Because I am using update panel feature and it is a real pain with JS codes. I can manage to get newly added options. Bu the important things is I don’t know how to generate the proper field.

Comment: How about something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009246/dynamically-create-textbox-on-button-click) then?